# Java remove duplicates from 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to do this problem:

" Prepare a rectangular array (with random natural positive dimensions) of int i variables
fill it with random values from the interval [0,10). Create and display a new board created from
input array by removing duplicates from each row (leaving only one
occurrence of each value). "

I am not allowed to use any libraries

I tried to change dublicates to a number out of the interva [0,10)  "1337" for example,
and then delete all "1337" thought it would be easier, but I have out of bounds exeption

Main function:

```
System.out.println("Zadanie 2");
int size = (int)(Math.random()*10);
int[][] arr = new int[size][size];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    }
}
removeDuplicates2D(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

My removeDuplicates2D function:

```
public static void removeDuplicates2D(int[][] tab) {
    int column = 0, row = 0;
    while (column != tab.length-1 || row != tab.length-1){
        if (column == 0 && row == 0){
            column++;
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if(tab[i][j] == tab[row][column]){
                    tab[row][column] = 1337;  // will change all duplicates to 1337
                }
            }
        }
        if(++column == tab.length-1){
            row++;
            column = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What to you mean by libraries?

Comment: The assignment appears to allow the final result to be a "ragged array" -- an array in which the rows have different number of columns. Is that correct?

Comment: Have a look at `tab[row][column]` and think about what this really means

Comment: Please show an example of a before and after array.

Comment: A [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of this type should show example input and expected output.  Since the "example input" is random in this case, I suggest modifying the code to print the array contents just after it is filled with random values and before the attempt to remove duplicates.  (This should be  done anyway, since it will be needed to verify the result of removing duplicates.) As a previous comment said, show the before,  actual after, and desired after arrays in the question.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer In removing the values and printing a jagged array, it doesn't really show where the duplicates were encountered.  Maybe that's not important.

Comment: Also, a good question of this type should include a copy of the error message, and the following stack trace. Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

Comment: It would be a good idea to try to debug this yourself. After all, if you want to become a software developer, or otherwise regularly create software, debugging will be a necessary skill. Running your code in a debugger allows the code to be executed one-line-at-a-time while monitoring variables.  You can also add `System.out.println (...` lines to your code to show values and follow the code.  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The problem specification is incomplete.  Does the scope of duplicate removal extend to the entire array, or just each row?  Is the result supposed to be ragged?  The statement _"Create and display a new board "_ could mean an array of the same dimensions as the input but with blank spaces.  If a number is duplicated, do you remove BOTH instances or keep one, and then, which one?  So many details left unspecified.  Maybe this was a test to see if you could ask the right questions? Also BTW `int size = (int)(Math.random()*10);` could return a size of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following 6x8 table

```
[4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0]
[3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 7, 8, 7]
[9, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 7]
[7, 8, 3, 9, 4, 9, 7, 4]
[8, 2, 8, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

The following would be the result of duplicates removed.

```
[4, 3, 2, 5, 0]
[7, 8]
[9, 6]
[1]
[]
[]
```

**Details**

- first, establish a single array to hold dups.  The location of the value `[0-9)` indicates if the value has been seen or not.  The value is its own index.
- then just iterate thru the array via rows and columns.

  - when you first encounter a value, if it's dup position is not 0, it must have been seen, so set the current tab value to 1337.
  - if not 0, then set the dup position to 1 and increment the `itemCount`. This count will be used to create the new row for first seen values.

Once the dups for a given row have been found

- create a replacement row using `itemCount`
- then iterate over row adding values that are not `1337`
- then assign that row to the current row position for the table.

```
public static void removeDuplicates2D(int[][] tab) {

    int[] dups = new int[10];

    for (int row = 0; row < tab.length; row++) {
        int itemCount = 0;
        int[] currentRow = tab[row];
        for (int col = 0; col < currentRow.length; col++) {
            int value = currentRow[col];
            if (dups[value] != 0) { // has been seen?
                currentRow[col] = 1337;
            } else {
                itemCount++;
                dups[value] = 1; // indicate value has been seen.
            }
        }

        int[] newRow = new int[itemCount];
        for (int k = 0, i = 0; i < currentRow.length; i++) {
            if (currentRow[i] != 1337) {
                newRow[k++] = currentRow[i];
            }
        }

        tab[row] = newRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example implies you overlooked a clause in the O/P question: *"leaving only one occurrence of each value*"

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer  I took that to mean removing duplicates from each row.  For example, if I find `8` somewhere in the matrix. I remove that value from each row, thereby leaving only one value in the matrix.  Without the OP providing the example I requested, I made an assumption.  But I see your point.  The fix is trivial, I must move my `dups` array inside the outerloop.

Comment: Ah. My interpretation was that each row should be independent of other rows. In addition, I misread your example. This is a 2nd example showing that including examples in the question is a good idea.

Comment: Exactly!  To paraphrase an old adage, "An example is worth a thousand words."

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I'm very sorry that i ignored your questions (my 1st time creating  a quastion on StackOverflow), but your team understood the assignment. Thank you both very much! Releted to my problem it was my 3 try to do this. I didn't understand that i could use for loop to divide 2D array into 1D. Debugging will be learnt. Could you give some more advices what should I do or learn to become better at programming?

Answer (score 0):

public class RemoveDuplicates2DArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Zadanie 2");
    int size = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int[][] arr = new int[size][size];

    // Fill array with random values in the range [0,10)
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }
    }

    removeDuplicates2D(arr);

    // Display modified array after removing duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
    }
}

public static void removeDuplicates2D(int[][] tab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        int[] row = tab[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < row.length; k++) {
                if (row[j] == row[k]) {
                    row[k] = -1; // Replace duplicates with -1 (outside [0,10) range)
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Shift elements to remove duplicates marked as -1
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            if (row[j] != -1) {
                row[index++] = row[j];
            }
        }
        
        // Fill the rest with 1337 (outside [0,10) range)
        while (index < row.length) {
            row[index++] = 1337;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: doesn't work, have you tried to execute that program?

Comment: A good answer should not be a code dump. A good answer should explain what is wrong with the O/P code, and how the code in the answer addresses the problem.  Since the O/P is a student,  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ОстапХом'як in what way did it fail? The code might work as the author intended, but the author misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer The output is very strange: it add random 1337 to the end of every 1d array. As i understand that problem input is for example:
{ {1,2,1},{1,5,3},{8,5,7}} and output should be {{1,2},{5,3},{8,7}} , but in his answer it's like:
{{1,2,1337},{1,5,1337},{8,5,1337}}

Comment: @ОстапХом'як Looks like a result of a misunderstanding to me. The person providing this answer read your question and thought the `1337` should remain in the array to preserve the original row lengths. This is an example why including examples in the question is a good idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).